# R row-wise runif() between 2 columns

Tags: r, random, uniform-distribution

I have the following data frame `DF` :

```
Min Max
10  20
14  34
9   29
... ...
```

and want to add a new column that samples a number between Min and Max of each row with uniform distribution. I've tried the below but give me the same number for all rows, meaning it's not sampling row by row as desired:

```
DF$random <- runif(1,min=DF$Min,max=DF$Max)
```

How may I achieve this?

Comment: Just put `nrow(DF)` instead of the 1? `runif(nrow(DF), DF$Min, DF$Max)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution

- just `runif()` (thanks to comments by @David Arenburg)

```
df$val <- with(df,runif(nrow(df),Min,Max))
```

- using `Vectorize()`

```
f <- Vectorize(function(x,y) runif(1,min=x,max=y),vectorize.args = c("x","y"))
df$val <- with(df,f(Min,Max))
```

such that

```
> df
  Min Max      val
1  10  20 14.51209
2  14  34 29.85087
3   9  29 22.97049
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Min = c(10L, 14L, 9L), Max = c(20L, 34L, 29L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding. Would it be also possible to sample more often closer to the min max boundaries? So instead of uniform distribution an upside-down bell curve.

Comment: @nba2020 well... I guess in that case you need to define your prob distribution first, e.g., an upside-down bell curve, and then use the defined distribution to generate random variables, rather than using the build-in functions

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
DF <- data.frame(Min = c(10,14,9), Max= c(20,32,29))
DF %>% mutate(new_sample = mapply(function(x, y) runif(1, x, y), Min, Max))
#   Min Max new_sample
# 1   1  10   2.581535
# 2  11  20  13.287205
# 3  21  30  23.546859
```